# Search in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Potentially a slightly misleading title but the problem is this:

I have a large dataframe with multiple columns. This looks a bit like

```
df = 
id   date        value
 A   01-01-2015    1.0
 A   03-01-2015    1.2
 ...
 B   01-01-2015    0.8
 B   02-01-2015    0.8
 ...
```

What I want to do is within each of the IDs I identify the date one week earlier and place the value on this date into e.g. a 'lagvalue' column. The problem comes  with not all dates existing for all ids so a simple .shift(7) won't pull the correct value [in this instance I guess I should put a NaN in].

I can do this with a lot of horrible iterating over the dates and ids to find the value, for example some rough idea

```
[
  df[
    df['date'] == df['date'].iloc[i] - datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)
  ][
    df['id'] == df['id'].iloc[i]
  ]['value']
  for i in range(len(df.index))
]
```

but I'm certain there is a 'better' way to do it that cuts down on time and processing that I just can't think of right now.

I could write a function using a groupby on the id and then look within that and I'm certain that would reduce the time it would take to perform the operation - is there a much quicker, simpler way [aka am I having a dim day]?

Comment: Good question, but I think I'm missing something: do you want to identify the date one week earlier than _one particular_ record with each ID? If so, how do you choose which of the records with each ID that should be? Or is it something else? (Understandably, I can't quite figure out what your iteration-based solution is doing... still working on it though)

Comment: @DavidZ for each of the dates [so for each date within the id aka for each row of the dataframe] I want to identify the date one week earlier and if there is a value associated for that item on that date to put it in a new column.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: I _think_ so. Let me see if I can figure something out.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question correctly, but doesn't `df['lagvalue'] = df['date'] - datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)` do the trick?

Comment: @durrrutti I don't want the date, I want the value from the value column where the date matches the date the week before.


If I had all of the dates possible then a .shift(+7) on the 'value' would be what I wanted.

Comment: can you post a sample of your desired result to understand more about the issue

Comment: I'm sure there is still a better way but as I easily fit within memory I just did a SQL type merge. Definitely just a bad day.

I've sorted it, thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic strategy is, for each id, to:

- Use date index
- Use `reindex` to expand the data to include all dates
- Use `shift` to shift 7 spots
- Use `ffill` to do last value interpolation.  *I'm not sure if you want this, or possibly* `bfill` *which will use the last value less than a week in the past. But simple to change*.  Alternatively, if you want NaN when not available 7 days in the past, you can just remove the `*fill` completely.
- Drop unneeded data

This algorithm gives `NaN` when the lag is too far in the past.

There are a few assumptions here. In particular that the dates are unique inside each id and they are sorted.  If not sorted, then use `sort_values` to sort by id and date.  If there are duplicate dates, then some rules will be needed to resolve which values to use.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('2001-01-01',periods=100)
dates = dates[::3]
A = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates,
                  'id':['A']*len(dates),
                  'value':np.random.randn(len(dates))})

dates = pd.date_range('2001-01-01',periods=100)
dates = dates[::5]
B = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates,
                  'id':['B']*len(dates),
                  'value':np.random.randn(len(dates))})
df = pd.concat([A,B])

with_lags = []
for id, group in df.groupby('id'):
    group = group.set_index(group.date)
    index = group.index
    group = group.reindex(pd.date_range(group.index[0],group.index[-1]))
    group = group.ffill()
    group['lag_value'] = group.value.shift(7)
    group = group.loc[index]
    with_lags.append(group)

with_lags = pd.concat(with_lags, 0)
with_lags.index = np.arange(with_lags.shape[0])
```